# How do I insert to SQL when a new WPMU site is created? I created a plugin, but it doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I am setting up a WordPress Multisite, and I have a plugin that uses a license. I looked through my database, and I found there are only two lines in the wp_options table that need to be filled in.

Currently, every time I create a new site, I need to go to the plugin settings and paste the license. I'd like to create a plugin that automatically places those two simple lines whenever a new site is created. I have the developer (unlimited sites) license, so this is not an issue.

From what I understand, this shouldn't be too difficult. I read though a bunch of sites, and came up with the code below. However, it's giving me an error when I activate it. I'm sure I'm missing something simple!

Thanks!

```html
 add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'ks_license' );

function ks_license ( $content ) {

$ks_status = 'ks_giveaways_license_status';
$ks_status_valid = 'valid';
$ks_license = 'ks_giveaways_license_status';
$ks_license_key = 'thisisakey';
$autoload = 'yes';

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'options';

$wpdb->insert( 
 $table_name, 
 array( 
  'option_name' => $ks_status, 
  'option_value' => $ks_status_valid, 
  'autoload' => $autoload, 
 ) 
 ;
 
 $wpdb->insert( 
 $table_name, 
 array( 
  'option_name' => $ks_license, 
  'option_value' => $ks_license_key, 
  'autoload' => $autoload, 
 ) 
 ;

}
```

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: It says there is an error on line 30 when I try to activate the plugin. It seems to be that final bracket. Honestly, I can't figure out why, though. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: And the actual error message is? They usually helpful in understanding the problem ;)

Comment: You're missing a ')' - one for the array and one for the insert

Comment: So, they should both go after the ";" am I right?

Comment: Also, does this mean the plug in should work? I'd be so happy with myself if I figured it out on my own lol.

Comment: Are you trolling me ;) ?   No - brackets 'bracket' stuff.  For each of the opening brackets of the insert ( .... you need a closing bracket BEFORE the ;.   And no I don't know if it'll work - that's just getting you past the syntax error.

Comment: Dude, I'm just learning this stuff. What's the point of this sassy snarkiness? Apparently, people aren't allowed to ask questions.

Comment: Not being snarky- see the wink? Just thought maybe.....since the code was so relatively well structured otherwise.